# SimpleCart additional information with custom columns

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart, simplecart

I am using the [SimpleCart Javascript Library](http://simplecartjs.org/).

I want to add an `id` to each product and when the user proceeds to checkout,
these `id`'s would be sent as well.

Instead of these columns, for example:

```
Name   Price
book   5$
```

I want to have a `Product Id` column include as well:

```
Id   Name   Price
3    book   5$
```

I've tried inserting the `id` into the options, but I had no luck doing so.

Can someone show me a detailed example doing so?

Comment: Give JSuar the bounty, his answer is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be set up like this:

In your simplecart set up under "cartColumns" add

```
{ attr: "id" , label: "ID" }
```

Like this:

```
cartColumns: [
        { attr: "image", label: "Item", view: "image"},
        //Name of the item
        { attr: "name" , label: "Name" },
        { attr: "id" , label: "ID" },
                    //etc………
```

Then you can use either:

```
<span class="item_id">ID:1</span>
```

or like this:

```
simpleCart.add({ name: "Shirt" , price: 4, id: 1 });
```

and it should show up in your columns.

Comment: I've set the element with the id of "item_id" instead of having it as a class name by mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation examples for [`item.get`](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-item-get) and [`item.set`](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-item-set) you should be able to set your own columns.

```
var myItem = simpleCart.add({ productId: "A12", name: "Awesome T-Shirt" , 
                              price: 10 , size: "Small" });

myItem.get( "productId" ); // A12
myItem.set( "productId" , "C54" );
myItem.get( "productId" ); // C54
```

Also, [each item has a built-in ID:](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-item-id) `simpleCart.Item.id()`

```
var myItem = simpleCart.add({ name: "Shirt" , price: 4 });
myItem.id(); // "SCS-1"
```

[You could also create a custom view for your own ID.](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/cart_columns)

> CREATING YOUR OWN VIEW
>
> You can create custom views for the cart by
>   setting the view to a function instead of a string. The function
>   should take two arguments, the item for that row, and the column
>   details you specify.
>
> ```
> { view: function( item , column ){
>         // return some html
>   } ,
>   label: "My Custom Column" 
> }
> ```

Comment: The ID-field does not seems however not to be passed along when you do SendForm.